# get begin(VEC) / end(VEC) by iterator between them

Tags: c++, vector, iterator

if we get some unclear iterator can we get the real address of vector or begin()/end() of that vector

```
vector<int> VEC1 (20);
vector<int> :: iterator it1 = VEC1.begin()+3;

vector<int> VEC2 (30);
vector<int> :: iterator it2 = VEC2.begin()+8;

vector<int> :: iterator it3 = (/**/)? it1 : it2 ;

// now, we are not clearly know what vector which it 3 refer
// this part can i do this ?, need something like that
vector<int> :: iterator it4 = begin( vector that it3 point to )   
vector<int> :: iterator it4 =   end( vector that it3 point to )

// Q : have any function which can do like last to line of code
```

thank you for your genius.

hope you please edit my question , it hard for me to arrange my word .

//

can i get (new iterator) that refer to begin of vector which (some iterator) point to

Comment: Sorry but it is unclear what you are asking for. What is the problem that you are trying to solve? Can you provide more information?

Comment: I think the question here is: given some arbitrary iterator, is it possible to derive the iterator's container. If so, the answer is: no.

Answer (score 0):

Normal and universal solution does not exist. Different containers use different allocators of its items. However, you can declare a pointer to the container and store it when deciding on it3

```
vector<int> VEC1 (20);
vector<int> :: iterator it1 = VEC1.begin()+3;

vector<int> VEC2 (30);
vector<int> :: iterator it2 = VEC2.begin()+8;

vector<int> *pVEC = NULL;
vector<int> ::iterator it3;

if (condition)
{
    it3 = it1;
    pVEC = &VEC1;
}
else
{
    it3 = it2;
    pVEC = &VEC2;
}

vector<int> ::iterator it4 = pVEC->begin();
vector<int> ::iterator it5 = pVEC->end();
```

You still do not know context of the container you are working, but the **operation** with it3, it4 and it5 are now **safe**, because they are guaranteed to refer to one container.